# Android TimePickerDialog selected time not passing through to the actual Countdown Timer

Tags: android, timepicker, countdowntimer

I've been working on getting a timepicker dialog to set my countdown timer.  I have tried many ways with many different results... none of them worked right.  I decided to experiment with some basic code which I will put below.

I cannot get the selected time (I called it selectedStartTime in the code below) to pass through into the actual countdown timer as startTime.  I can only get the timer to work right when I use the preset startTime = 10000 (or any number).  I don't want the startTime to be a set number.  I need it to come from the OnTimeSetListener in the time picker box.

I will be forever grateful to anyone that can show me how to change the code so that the selected time in the dialog box is actually used in the timer.

Complete XML code for: activity_simple_timer_test.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Start" />

<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:padding="10dip">

    <TableRow>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/timer"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingRight="10dip"
            android:text="Time: " />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/timeElapsed"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingRight="10dip"
            android:text="Time elapsed: " />
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Complete Java code for: SimpleTimerTest.java

```
package com.YOURPACKAGE INFO;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.TimePickerDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.TimePicker;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class SimpleTimerTest extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

private MalibuCountDownTimer countDownTimer;
private long timeElapsed;
private boolean timerHasStarted = false;
private Button startB;
private TextView text;
private TextView timeElapsedView;
int selectedStartTime;
// don't want to use a predefined startTime
private final long startTime = 10000;
private final long interval = 1000;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_simple_timer_test);
    startB = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.button);
    startB.setOnClickListener(this);

    text = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.timer);
    timeElapsedView = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.timeElapsed);
    countDownTimer = new MalibuCountDownTimer(startTime, interval);
    text.setText(text.getText() + String.valueOf(startTime));
}

TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener onTimeSetListener = new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
    @Override
    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
        selectedStartTime = ((hourOfDay*3600000)+(minute*60000));
        // I can't get this variable to pass through into the countdown timer
    }
};

@Override
public void onClick(View v)   {

    TimePickerDialog d = new TimePickerDialog(SimpleTimerTest.this, onTimeSetListener, 1, 0, true);
    d.setTitle("Pick Sleep Duration   hour:min");
    d.setCancelable(true);
    d.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "Start", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            if (which == DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE) {

                if (!timerHasStarted) {
                    countDownTimer.start();
                    timerHasStarted = true;
                    startB.setText("Stop");
                } else {
                    countDownTimer.cancel();
                    timerHasStarted = false;
                    startB.setText("Timer was already running");
                }
            }
        }
    });
    d.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE, "Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            if (which == DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE) {
                countDownTimer.cancel();
                timerHasStarted = false;
                startB.setText("Restart");
            }
        }
    });
    d.show();
}

public class MalibuCountDownTimer extends CountDownTimer    {
    public MalibuCountDownTimer(long startTime, long interval)
    {
        super(startTime, interval);
    }
    @Override
    public void onFinish()        {
        text.setText("Time's up!");
        timeElapsedView.setText("Time Elapsed: " + String.valueOf(startTime));
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "finished", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
        toast.show();
    }
    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished)        {
        text.setText("Time remain:" + millisUntilFinished);
        timeElapsed = startTime - millisUntilFinished;
        timeElapsedView.setText("Time Elapsed: " + String.valueOf(timeElapsed));
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not completely sure what you're trying to achieve, just create instance of your `MalibuCountDownTimer` in method `onTimeSet`, this method will be called only when user selected time.

Comment: I tried that before.  The problem I had was that the timer would not cancel.  I was never able to get countDownTimer.cancel() to work right.  I spend a long time on that one.  I always ended up with a timer that would not cancel or multiple timers running at the same time.  I'll try and revisit that and see if I can get it working, but I really had issues going that way.  I was just hoping there was an easy way to move that selected time out of the method and into the timer where it is.

Comment: Then just check timer for null and cancel it first if it already created.

Comment: Well, it took all day and a lot of messing around, but I managed to get it into the onTimeSet method AND got it all working right.  I might still look like a mess, but at least it is a working mess.